# How to measure Token confidence or probability

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

Im using Spacy and NLTK for POS tagging and I would like to get the tagging confidence or probability for each token. Seems the Spacy has the token.prob attribute, but is was removed from the 3+ versions.
When i use it all words returns -20 score.

```
>>> nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_sm")
>>> doc = nlp("O gato está na mesa")
>>> token = doc[1]

>>> print(token.pos_, token.prob)

NOUN -20.0
```

I dont have a trainned data base, so Im tring to measure the confidence of the POS tag models from Spacy and NLTK.